# ldap query to get disabled user records with whenchanged within 30 days

Tags: ssis, ldap

I am a trying to run an LDAP query to get a list of disabled users with `whenchanged` attribute within last 30 days. The query

```
SELECT Name, description, profilePath, homeDrive, whenChanged, distinguishedName,userAccountControl 
FROM 'LDAP://wusrcpsakc07.abc.com:3268/dc=SAK,dc=com' 
WHERE objectCategory='user' and userAccountcontrol = '514'
```

runs fine. When I add the `whenchanged` attribute, I get an error

```
SELECT Name, description, profilePath, homeDrive, whenChanged, distinguishedName,userAccountControl 
FROM 'LDAP://wusrcpsakc07.abc.com:3268/dc=SAK,dc=com' 
WHERE objectCategory='user' and userAccountcontrol = '514'
and whenChanged > getDate() - 30
```

Comment: What the hack is that? How are you running SQL against LDAP?

Comment: i am trying to have an SSIS package run against  windows AD, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I am familiar with the SSIS/LDAP integration, I thought I'd build on Pavel's direction.

I'm assuming you're using the ADO.NET source for your data flow. Get your package working fine with your filter excluding the date logic.

### Variables

The first thing you'll need to do is create some SSIS Variables. I like Variables and see at least 4 Variable that need to be created.

- SourceDate - DateTime - 2014-04-19 - EvaluateAsExpression = True. Formula = `DATEADD( "d",-30, @[System::StartTime]  )`
- ADTime - String - 20140419000000.0Z - EvaluateAsExpression = True. Formula = `(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(@[User::SourceDate]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + "000000.0Z"`

  - If you're feeling pedantic and want to build out the full time part, the formula becomes `(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(@[User::SourceDate]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("hour", @[User::SourceDate] ), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("minute", @[User::SourceDate] ), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("second", @[User::SourceDate] ), 2) +".0Z"`
- QueryBase - String - `SELECT Name, description, profilePath, homeDrive, whenChanged, distinguishedName, userAccountControl FROM 'LDAP://DC=home,DC=billfellows,DC=net' WHERE objectCategory='user' and userAccountcontrol = '514' AND whenChanged >= '`
- Query - String - SELECT 1 as Foo - EvaluateAsExpression = True. Formula = `@[User::QueryBase] +  @[User::ADTime] + "'"`

That looks like a lot, but it's not. Let's break it down. 
- SourceDate is going to calculate 30 days before the package's start time. 
- ADTime - this builds out a string of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.0Z (date followed by time parts for those critiquing the ambiguous usage of Ms) These will be 0 padded values to ensure months like May are expressed as 05 and not 5
- QueryBase - This provides the basic framework of your query, with `AND whenChanged >= '` That's an incomplete query, does not parse but it's the static piece
- Query - This uses QueryBase and ADTime to add the "dynamic" element into our query. Since AD can't handle the dynamic portion, this is how we will trick it. We build our query string per execution by swapping in the date and time portion.

### Using it

The ADO.NET query editor is in a tie for most cantankerous SSIS item you may use on a semi-regular basis (yes, there's an award for this). Unlike the OLE DB Source component, you can't specify within the editor itself that you'd like to have it driven by a Variable. 
Instead, you'll need to right click on the Data Flow Task and select Properties.

In the resultant window, you'll find the Expressions ellipses and click on it.

Choose the one that looks like [Name of ADO.NET Source Component].[SqlCommand] and assign it the value of `@[User::Query]`. In the image below, you can see that I called my source component "ADO AD"

[image]

### Why do it this way?

Support and maintainability are my primary reasons for doing it this way. By building out the Variables individually, I can troubleshoot anything that's going wrong by putting a breakpoint in the package and inspecting elements or adding a script task that fires and information message with the relevant information. While I *could* have put all that Variable logic into the source component's SqlCommand property, debugging that is impossible because SSIS does not provide you a mechanism for inspecting the the expressions on an Object.

### Caution

514 is not disabled. I mean, it *is* but there are other values for `userAccountControl` that could indicate disabled. It's really a question of whether the userAccountControl, when bitwise ANDed with 2 yields 2. See the first link at the end for my sad tale of woe.

> For the userAccountControl a value of 512 is an active AD account, 514 is a disabled account. I have that in documentation from another team. Unfortunately, that's not quite accurate. That field is really a bitmask. A year or two after we implemented my package, we learned that inactive people were showing up in feeds which was impossible, we filter them (514s) out. I then learned that a 514 is really just a 512 (NORMAL_ACCOUNT) ORed with 2 (ACCOUNTDISABLE). An automated process had been implemented that created accounts with expired passwords or some such nonsense which had a net result of disabled accounts reading as 546 (regular became 544 - Account Enabled - Require user to change password at first logon).

- http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html
- http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/11/biml-active-directory-ssis-data-source.html

### Biml

I'm rather fond of using Biml with SSIS as it allows me to "share my work" with others without mailing packages about. The following code is based off my [Biml Active Directory SSIS Data Source](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/11/biml-active-directory-ssis-data-source.html) post with some tweaks thrown in for this particular case. Do note, I had to double click the ADO.NET source component, click Columns and then I got my warnings

> "The data type "System.Object" found on column "" is not supported for the ADO AD. This column will be converted to  DT_NTEXT"

I'm sure there's a way to get the Biml to generate the exact package but, I can live with a few clicks for so little "work".

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <AdoNetConnection Name="AD" ConnectionString="Data Source=HOME.BILLFELLOWS.NET;Provider=ADsDSOObject;Integrated Security=SSPI;" Provider="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_23741312" DelayValidation="true" ForcedExecutionValueDataType="Empty" Language="None" ConstraintMode="Parallel" VersionBuild="5" CreatorName="bfellows" CreatorComputerName="WESTMARCH" CreationDate="2014-05-19T22:28:49">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="ADTime" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(@[User::SourceDate]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + "000000.0Z"</Variable>
                <Variable Name="ADTimePedantic" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(@[User::SourceDate]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::SourceDate]), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("hour", @[User::SourceDate] ), 2)+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("minute", @[User::SourceDate] ), 2)+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("second", @[User::SourceDate] ), 2)+".0Z"</Variable>
                <Variable Name="Query" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">@[User::QueryBase] +  @[User::ADTime] + "'"</Variable>
                <Variable Name="QueryBase" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude">SELECT Name, description, profilePath, homeDrive, whenChanged, distinguishedName, userAccountControl FROM 'LDAP://DC=home,DC=billfellows,DC=net' WHERE objectCategory='user' and userAccountcontrol = '514' AND whenChanged >= '</Variable>
                <Variable Name="RowCountSource" DataType="Int32" IncludeInDebugDump="Include">0</Variable>
                <Variable Name="SourceDate" DataType="DateTime" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">DATEADD( "d",-30, @[System::StartTime]  )</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT AD Extract" DelayValidation="true" ForcedExecutionValueDataType="Empty">
                    <Expressions>
                        <Expression ExternalProperty="[ADO AD].[SqlCommand]">@[User::Query]</Expression>
                    </Expressions>
                    <Transformations>
                        <AdoNetSource Name="ADO AD" LocaleId="None" ConnectionName="AD">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT Name, description, profilePath, homeDrive, whenChanged, distinguishedName, userAccountControl FROM 'LDAP://DC=home,DC=billfellows,DC=net' WHERE objectCategory='user' and userAccountcontrol = '514' AND whenChanged >= '20140419000000.0Z'</DirectInput>
                        </AdoNetSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="bit bucket Active" LocaleId="None">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="CSPL Filter Inactive Accounts.ActiveAccounts" SsisName="CSPL Filter Inactive Accounts_ActiveAccounts_bit bucket Active" />
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="bit bucket InActive" LocaleId="None">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="CSPL Filter Inactive Accounts.Default" SsisName="CSPL Filter Inactive Accounts_Default_bit bucket InActive" />
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <ConditionalSplit Name="CSPL Filter Inactive Accounts" LocaleId="None">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="DER Check Account Status.Output" SsisName="DER Check Account Status_Output_CSPL Filter Inactive Accounts" />
                            <OutputPaths>
                                <OutputPath Name="ActiveAccounts">
                                    <Expression>IsActive</Expression>
                                </OutputPath>
                            </OutputPaths>
                        </ConditionalSplit>
                        <DataConversion Name="DC NTEXT to DT_WSTR" LocaleId="None">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="RC Source.Output" SsisName="RC Source_Output_DC NTEXT to DT_WSTR" />
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="distinguishedName" TargetColumn="distinguishedName" DataType="String" Length="500" />
                                <Column SourceColumn="description" TargetColumn="description" DataType="String" Length="500" />
                                <Column SourceColumn="Name" TargetColumn="Name" DataType="String" Length="500" />
                                <Column SourceColumn="userAccountControl" TargetColumn="userAccountControl" DataType="Int32" />
                                <Column SourceColumn="profilePath" TargetColumn="profilePath" DataType="String" Length="500" />
                                <Column SourceColumn="homeDrive" TargetColumn="homeDrive" DataType="String" Length="500" />
                            </Columns>
                        </DataConversion>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Check Account Status" LocaleId="None">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="DC NTEXT to DT_WSTR.Output" SsisName="DC NTEXT to DT_WSTR_Output_DER Check Account Status" />
                            <Columns>
                                <Column Name="IsActive" DataType="Boolean">(([userAccountControl] &amp; 2) == 2) ? false : true</Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <RowCount Name="RC Source" LocaleId="None" VariableName="User.RowCountSource">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="ADO AD.Output" SsisName="ADO AD_Output_RC Source" />
                        </RowCount>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
            <Connections>
                <Connection ConnectionName="AD" />
            </Connections>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

### Results

Since I haven't disabled any accounts in the past 30 days, there's nothing to see here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks billinkc and @Pavel Horal. That worked like a charm. Like Pavel mentioned, LDAP takes only simple conditions and this answer helped convert the date to the required zulu format for comparison.