# Import Active Directory to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory, business-intelligence

I'm working on a Microsoft BI project.

I am currently in the process of connecting my systems to SQL Server. I want to connect my Active Directory to a table in SQL Server and I want to sync to one table per hour. This means that every hour the details of the Active Directory will be updated.

I realized that it is necessary to use SSIS to do this I would be happy for help to connect my AD to SQL Server with the help of SSIS.

Comment: Is there a particular part of the AD that you want?  In any but the smallest corporations the AD tends to be *huge*.  Making a SQL copy of an entire forest every hour is a very strange thing that may have many adverse effects on your AD, network, security and domain-wide performance.  If you are just looking to backup your AD, I believe that there are other options available.

Answer (score 1):

There are two routes available to you to sync AC user classes to a table. You can use an ADO source in an SSIS Data Flow Task or you can write custom .NET code as part of a Script Source. The right answer depends on your team's ability to maintain and troubleshoot a particular solution as well as the size of your AD tree/forest. If you're a small shop (under a thousand) anything is going to work. If you're a larger shop, then you need to worry about the query mechanism and the total rows returned as there is an upper boundary of how many results can be returned in a single query. In that case, then a script task likely makes more sense as you can more easily write a query to pull all the accounts that start with A, B, etc. I've never worked with Hebrew, so I assume one could do a similar filter for aleph, bet, etc.

### General steps

Identify your domain controller as you need to know what server to ask information from. I do not know how to deal with Azure Active Directory requests as I believe it works a bit different there but haven't had client work that needed it.

Create a Connection Manager for ADO.NET . Use the ".Net Providers for OleDb\OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services" and point that to your DC.

Write a query to pull back the data you need. Based on the comment, it seems you want something like this

```
SELECT
    distinguishedName
,   mail
,   samaccountname
,   mobile
,   telephoneNumber
,   objectSid
,   userAccountControl
,   title
,   sn
FROM
    'LDAP://DC=domain,DC=net'
WHERE
    sAMAccountType = 805306368
ORDER BY
    sAMAccountName ASC
```

Using that query, we'll add a Data Flow Task and within it, add an ADO.NET Source. Configure it to use our ADO.NET Connection manager and use the above query (adjusting for the LDAP line and any other fields you do/don't need)

Add an OLE DB Connection Manager to your package and point it to the database that will record the data.

Add an OLE DB Destination to the Data Flow and connect the output line from the ADO.NET Source to this destination. Pick the table in the drop down list and on the Columns tab, make sure you have all of your columns connected. You might run into issues where the data types don't match so you'll need to figure out how to handle that - either change your table definition to match the source or you need to add data conversion/derived columns components to the data flow to mangle the data into the correct shape.

You might be tempted to pull in group membership. Do not. Make that a separate task as a person might be a member of many groups (at one client, I am in 94 groups). Also, the MemberOf data type is a DistinguishedName, DN, which SSIS cannot handle. So, check your types before you add them into an AD query.

References

[ldap query to get disabled user records with whenchanged within 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741312/ldap-query-to-get-disabled-user-records-with-whenchanged-within-30-days/23751008#23751008)

http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html
http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/11/biml-active-directory-ssis-data-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular part of the AD that you want? In any but the smallest corporations the AD tends to be *huge*. Making a SQL copy of an entire forest every hour is a very strange thing that may have many adverse effects on your AD, network, security and domain-wide performance.

If you are just looking to backup your AD, I believe that there are other options available, specific to the Windows AD (maybe even built-in, I'm not an AD expert).

If you really, truly want to do this here is a link to get you started:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/79bb4879-4d82-4a41-81a4-c62afc6c4b1e/copy-all-ad-objects-to-sql-database?forum=winserverDS.  You can find many more articles on this just by Googling "Copy AD to Sql".

However, heed the warnings well:  the AD is effectively a multi-domain-wide distributed database, attempting to copy it into a centralized database like SQL Server every hour is contra-indicated.  You are really fighting against its design.

---

**UPDATE Based on the Comments:**

Basically you've got too much in one question here.  Sql Server, SSIS and the Active Directory (AD) are each huge subjects in and of themselves and the first time that you attempt to use all of them together you will run into many individual issues depending on your environment, experience and specific project goals.  We cannot anticipate all of them in a single answer on this site.

You need to start using the information you have from the following links to begin to implement this yourself, and then ask *specific* questions as you run into problems along the way.

Here are the links that you can start with,

- The link I provided above from MS:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/79bb4879-4d82-4a41-81a4-c62afc6c4b1e/copy-all-ad-objects-to-sql-database?forum=winserverDS
- The link that you provided in the comments that explains how to setup ADSI as a linked server and how to use T-SQL on it: https://yiengly.wordpress.com/2018/04/08/query-active-directory-in-sql-server-with-linked-server/
- This one explain how to use AD from within an SSIS DataFlow task (but is limited to 1000 rows): https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/05/importing-data-from-active-directory-using-ssis/
- This related one explains how to use AD within an SSIS Script task to get around the DataFlow task limits: https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/09/get-around-active-directory-paging-on-ssis-import/

As you work your way through this you may run into specific problems, which you can ask about at https://dba.stackexchange.com which has more specific expertise with Sql Server and SSIS.

Based on your goals, I think that you will want to use a staging table approach.  That is, use your AD/Sql query to import all of the AD users records into a new/empty temporary table that has the same column definition as your production table, then use a Merge query to find and update the changed user records and insert the new user records (this is called a Differential or Type II update).

Comment: Thanks but
This is not my intention I need to show users in intelligence I need to copy users to SQL I need to copy every hour only missing users in SQL I make the copy to a table of users only
The missing are not the rule over and over again

Comment: I want to do the data retrieval as in this example just by query is timed by SSIS and transfer the information to the table.

https://yiengly.wordpress.com/2018/04/08/query-active-directory-in-sql-server-with-linked-server/



SELECT * FROM OpenQuery (
ADSI,
'SELECT mail, mobile, telephoneNumber, title, sn, givenName, SAMAccountName
FROM '' LDAP: // OU = <your-users-ou>, DC = <your>, DC = <company>, DC = com ''
WHERE objectClass = '' user ''
AND NOT objectClass = '' computer ''
'
) AS tblADS
ORDER BY SAMAccountName

Comment: @חןחכמון I have updated my answer based on your recent comments.